# GSON: Is there any way to return 2 different date formats while marshalling

Tags: java, gson, marshalling

`GsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` is appending 00:00:00 for date only fields.
Is there any way to override this behavior as requirement is to show date only as well as date with time.

Comment: In Java, there is no "date only fields". In java "The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision" so you don't have a way to separate the concept between "date" and "date with time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a "date" a `java.util.Date` where hours, minutes and seconds are equal to zero, and "date with time" a `Date` where they are not. You coud do something like that:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new CustomDateJsonSerializer());
```

with `CustomDateJsonSerializer` define like this:

```
public class CustomDateJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private static final TimeZone UTC_TIME_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
    private static final Pattern DATE_TIME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String asString = json.getAsString();
        try {
            if (DATE_PATTERN.matcher(asString).matches()) {
                return getDateFormat().parse(asString);
            } else if (DATE_TIME_PATTERN.matcher(asString).matches()) {
                return getDateTimeFormat().parse(asString);
            } else {
                throw new JsonParseException("Could not parse to date: " + json);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Could not parse to date: " + json, e);
        }
    }

    private static DateFormat getDateFormat() {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(UTC_TIME_ZONE);
        return simpleDateFormat;
    }

    private static DateFormat getDateTimeFormat() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(UTC_TIME_ZONE);
        return dateFormat;
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(UTC_TIME_ZONE);
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        String dateFormatted;
        if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            dateFormatted = getDateFormat().format(date);
        } else {
            dateFormatted = getDateTimeFormat().format(date);
        }
        return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormatted);
    }
}
```

Comment: The date format should be **`yyyy-MM-dd`**, not `YYYY-MM-dd`

Comment: ... and should be using **`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`**, not `Calendar.HOUR` and also need to check `Calendar.MILLISECOND`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define two different Gson TypeAdapter implementations.

Then specify on the appropriate Date field on your serializable class which TypeAdapter you wish to use.

Use a custom type adapter like below with the field annotation:

```
@JsonAdapter(DatePartOnlyGsonAdapter.class)
Date whenever; 

public Date getWhenever() {
    return whenever;
}
```

Here's a type adapter which outputs just the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, using Java8's `LocalDate` to do formatting, when you have inherited code using `java.util.Date` properties :(

```
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatePartOnlyGsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Date> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Date src) throws IOException {
        if (src == null) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        LocalDate d = new java.sql.Date(src.getTime()).toLocalDate();
        out.value(d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    }

    @Override
    public Date read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Gson Date reader not implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time | java.time

If you want a date only without any time of day or time zone, use another library rather than the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

Instead use either Joda-Time or java.time package in Java 8. Both offer a `LocalDate` class.

Bonus: By default both use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for generating and parsing String representations.